# Can a user1 from Org1 ensure the request from user2 from Org2 is valid by checking with the corresponding CA?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, x509certificate, ca

I am setting up a solution to transfer data securely and in a permissioned manner between users of two different organisations (Data resides within organisation database system and not on Blockchain). From Blockchain controls like abac (attribute based access control), I can make the user get relevant details needed to access data. Now, I am writing a middleware for the user in the second organisation to call and get the data. In this context, is it possible for the middleware to check the user from second organisation is actually who he claims to be by checking with the CA of the second organization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are admin of both organizations you can check any user.

```
fabric-ca-client identity list --id user1
```

You can use NodeJS API for the same operation

Check this

https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control